# Cursor.visible doesn't seem to work in Standalone

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, mouse-cursor

I am writing a multi-display application for which I need to make the mouse cursor invisible. I am using the following code:

```
 public class HideCursor : MonoBehaviour {
     public Texture2D CursorToUse;
     void Start () {
         UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = false;
     }
     void Update () {
         UnityEngine.Cursor.visible = false;
     }
 }
```

This works **fine in the editor**, but does **not** seem to work at all **in standalone**.

Is anyone else experiencing this? What can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here.  Firstly the unity standalone window has to be focused in order for unity to hide the cursor.  Secondly, make sure no other scripts are setting `Cursor.lockState` or `Cursor.visible`, because that could cause the cursor to reappear in certain circumstances.  A few of the demo scripts use them so watch out.

The unity documentation for [Cursor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.html) explictly also states that:

> Linux falls back to software cursors on unsupported platforms.

You could also try using `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked` since some people reported that working.

If nothing works, a good hack is setting the texture of the cursor to an empty texture using [Cursor.SetCursor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor.SetCursor.html).

Finally Google gives a lot of results if you look up [UnityEngine.Cursor.visible not working](https://www.google.com/search?q=UnityEngine.Cursor.visible%20not%20working&rct=j&safe=active&ssui=on), so start there if nothing else works.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc. Unfortunately, I fear this is because my application is multidisplay - If you run the standalone app and then focus another window, drag that window onto the second display and then move the mouse around display 2; you'll see that whilst the cursor is not intersecting with the output on display 1, it is visible. As soon as you move the cursor onto display 1, it will vanish again. This is very undesirable behaviour in my case. I need the mouse to be invisible whenever it is intersecting with display 2 or more

Comment: P.S. I have tried setting an invisible cursor, and the same problem still occurs

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I think you could use `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked` to lock the actual cursor inside one of the windows and then mouse movements could move a simulated mouse that runs in a canvas that you could easily turn on/off.

Comment: You are correct, however that's something I absolutely don't want to do - users need to be freely able to interact with other windows whilst my app is running.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In that case I'm not sure anymore.  Unity is supposed to be a game engine more that anything else, and usually a user won't be multitasking in and out of the window.  Ask on unity forums, you may have to wait a bit and bump your question a few times, but eventually a high level user will help you.  They might have a solution for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have actually submitted a bug report and they have just got back to me to acknowledge that it is a fault which needs fixing. Many thanks for your answer!